# In netbeans 7.2 - Change color of EOL character

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

Is it possible to change the color of the netbeans 7.2 eol character?

As seen here:

[image]

I would prefer it to be a light grey like the space character - the dark black color is quite distracting (IMHO).

Comment: Do you find how change color?

Comment: No. Wasn't able to. I gave up on netbeans. I moved to [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **NetBeans 7.1.2** you can change the color by doing the following:

- *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Fonts & Colors*
- Select the *Syntax* tab and then click on the *Whitespace*.

You should be able to change the color of eol character by picking it from the available ones one the right-side panel.

I guess this would also work for NetBeans 7.2.

---

PS: that was an old question, but I thought it should have an answer anyway :)

Comment: It look like broken in > 7.1.2: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215172 (i've test on 7.2 and 7.2.1 it don't work for EOL)

Comment: Broken in 7.4 as well